# FKeditor and Spring MVC Maven integration step by step

Tags: spring, fckeditor

I want to use Fckeditor in my spring mvc. Could you provide instruction or link to set up step by step?

I did below steps but when I run, 404 not found [/springmvc/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html ]is showing.

Could you check me what I am wrong and guide me?

Firstly, as per documentation I added below code in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.fckeditor</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And in web.xml file, I added below code.

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>ConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
          net.fckeditor.connector.ConnectorServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>
    /resources/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/*
  </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After that I download FCKeditor_2.6.8.zip file and extract in the src/main/resources folder.

In the jsp page, I added taglib, javascript and tag.

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.fckeditor.net" prefix="FCK" %>`

> ```
> function FCKeditor_OnComplete(editorInstance) {
>   window.status = editorInstance.Description;
> }
> ```

```
<FCK:editor instanceName="EditorDefault">
  <jsp:attribute name="value">This is some <strong>sample text
      </strong>. You are using <a href="http://www.fckeditor.net">
      FCKeditor</a>.
  </jsp:attribute>
</FCK:editor>
```

But Fckeditor is still not working.

Could you guide me which is wrong?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

i have used ckeditor, below are configrations

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ckeditor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ckeditor-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

in jsp file

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ckeditor" uri="http://ckeditor.com"%>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="%=request.getContextPath()%>/common/script/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<form:textarea path="body" maxlength="5000" />                                                       <ckeditor:replace replace="body" basePath="../ckeditor/" />
```

make sure you copy js files also and copy it and specify it in jsp

Comment: Thank you Jigar Parekh. It is working now as per your instruction. For me, I need to place ckeditor in the resources folder.

Comment: good to know that problem is solved, accept answer so it can help others too.